# Material UI DropDownMenu taking 100% height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a DropDownMenu in a specific page that is rendered inside a table column.

[image: Imgur]

When I click to open the menu, it opens with 100% of the page height.

[image: Imgur]

I found nothing like this in the documentation, nor the community.

I have no relative/absolute container relation with the child components.

I tried to set `maxHeight`, but the same occurs.

Thank you for the help.

EDIT:

Some code.

This is the component where the DropDownMenu is instantiated:

```jsx
export default ({
  variables,
}: Props) => (
  <Table multiSelectable>
    <TableHeader enableSelectAll>
      <TableRow>
        <TableHeaderColumn className={styles.headerColumn}>Variável</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn className={styles.headerColumn}>Tipo</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn className={styles.headerColumn}>Linha 01</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn className={styles.headerColumn}>Linha 02</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn className={styles.headerColumn}>Linha 03</TableHeaderColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
      {variables.map(variable => (
        <TableRow key={variable.id}>
          <TableRowColumn className={styles.column}>{variable.header}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn className={styles.columnDropdown}>
            <DropDownMenu value={variable.type}>
              <MenuItem value="numerical" primaryText="Numérica" />
              <MenuItem value="categorical" primaryText="Categórica" />
              <MenuItem value="key" primaryText="Chave" />
              <MenuItem value="answer" primaryText="Resposta" />
            </DropDownMenu>
          </TableRowColumn>
          {variable.line.map(line => (
            <TableRowColumn key={line} className={styles.column}>{line}</TableRowColumn>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
);
```

This code uses a SASS Module:

```scss
.headerColumn {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

.column {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.columnDropdown {
  @extend .column;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

I have no floats and nothing absolute in this component. Analysing the open Menu, it is taking `top: 0` and `max-height: 1014px;`. Can't say why.

Comment: have you tried to define the `style={{height: 300}}` with DropDown, i think that should work.

Comment: Are you using float ?

Comment: Give us the code so that we can see where the problem is .

Comment: @MayankShukla I tried, but the container still gets the entire height. The Menu picks the style and even show a scroll bar. The problem is the container around the Menu, apparently.

Comment: @YashYadav I edited the question. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
[data-reactroot] {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

This was messing it up.